# Program shutdown on Synchronize

Tags: multithreading, freepascal, lazarus

I want to call a `callbackmethod` in it's own Thread. The `callbackMethod` will be implemented as interface.

I've declared a Thread like following:

```
CustomfunctionCallbackThread = Class(TThread)
        protected
            procedure Execute; override;

        private
            var mCallId: String;
            var mCallbackMethod: ICustomfunctionCallback;
            var mParam: pCustomParam;
            var mError: integer;

            procedure callCallbackMethod;

        public
            procedure setData(callbackObject: pCustomfunctionCallbackObject);

     end;
```

Now I'm calling that Thread like:

```
procedure classname.method(param :pCustomParam; callId: String; error: integer; callback: ICustomfunctionCallback);
var callbackObject: ^CustomfunctionCallbackObject;
var callbackThread: CustomfunctionCallbackThread;  
begin
  callbackObject.param:= param;
  callbackObject.error:= error;  
  callbackObject.callId:= callId; 
  callbackObject.callbackMethod:= callback; 

  callbackThread:= CustomfunctionCallbackThread.Create(true);
  callbackThread.setData(callbackObject);
  callbackThread.FreeOnTerminate:= true;
  callbackThread.Start;
end;
```

The setData function looks like:

```
procedure CustomfunctionCallbackThread.setData(callbackObject: pCustomfunctionCallbackObject);
begin
    mCallId:=callbackObject.callId;
    mParam:=callbackObject.param;
    mError:=callbackObject.error;
    mCallbackMethod:=callbackObject.callbackMethod;
end;
```

and my execute function looks like:

```
procedure CustomfunctionCallbackThread.Execute;
begin
    mCallbackMethod.callCustomfunctionCallback(mParam, mCallId, mError);
end;
```

Now, the callback method (interface) looks like this:

```
procedure CustomfunctionCallback.callCustomfunctionCallback(param: pCustomParam; callId: String; error: integer);
var receivedCustomfunctionCallback: string;
begin
  receivedCustomfunctionCallback:= 'CustomfunctionCallback received: Param - ' +
    PAnsiChar(param^.getKey(0)) + ' | Value - ' + PAnsiChar(param^.getValue(0));

  Form_PAis.Utf8Convert(receivedCustomfunctionCallback);
  Dispose(param);
end;
```

The function runs like it should, but the debug mode will be exited automatically, after that.

If it's look like that:

```
procedure CustomfunctionCallback.callCustomfunctionCallback(param: pCustomParam; callId: String; error: integer);
var receivedCustomfunctionCallback: string;
begin
  receivedCustomfunctionCallback:= 'CustomfunctionCallback received: Param - ' +
    PAnsiChar(param^.getKey(0)) + ' | Value - ' + PAnsiChar(param^.getValue(0));

  Form_PAis.output.Append(receivedCustomfunctionCallback);
  Dispose(param);
end;
```

It will crash(not exit) at

```
Form_PAis.output.Append(receivedCustomfunctionCallback);
```

Do you got an idea, how to fix the problem?

Comment: Please cut this down and supply a complete program that we can compile and run. It would also make a huge difference to us if you could use standard naming and layout conventions. This code is making my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions that escape a thread proc will cause the whole process to be shut down. Put an exception handler inside your threadproc (Execute method) to trap all exceptions. Something like this:

```
procedure CustomfunctionCallbackThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    mCallbackMethod.callCustomfunctionCallback(mParam, mCallId, mError);
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      // output or log this error somewhere.
    end; 
  end;
end;
```

The code above should at least help prevent the whole process from tumbling down. You still need to find and fix what is causing the exception to begin with.

Set a breakpoint in your callback function, on or before the suspected Form_PAis.output... line.  Run the app until it stops for the breakpoint. In the debugger, use the watch window or inspectors to check the values of the variables and properties involved.  Is Form_PAis null?  Is Form_PAis.output null?  Check the variables of the statement prior, too, since the line number attributed to an exception is sometimes one line past the actual cause.

Comment: Since Delphi 6, `Classes.ThreadProc` calls `Thread.Execute` and protects it with a try/except. So this answer is not accurate unless Daniel is using D5 or earlier.

Comment: I'm using the actual version of Lazarus

Comment: It is programmed with {$mode delphi}

Comment: So what? Why are you hiding that information from us? Anyway, Danny's answer is still wrong. Because the FPC thread proc catches unhandled exceptions.

Comment: I didn't knew, that this is important. Sorry ^^

Comment: My answer stands for Delphi versions prior to Delphi 6. The OP did not indicate a Delphi version, and adding an additional exception handler to the thread proc will do no harm in later products that do have an exception handler around the thread proc.  And a process that just goes poof! with no error message at all is a classic example of an exception escaping from a thread proc.  The other possibility is an hwnd proc that points to a garbage address, but that doesn't seem likely here.

Comment: Only Ian Boyd is still using D5!!  ;-)

Comment: An answer which only applies to the most recent version of a product would be just as "wrong" given this question's broad categorization.

Comment: You're welcome to them.  If this Q had indicated FPC or Delphi-ex, I wouldn't have come anywhere near it.

Comment: FPC is mostly as older Delphi in this respect. Changes like TMonitor and even TThread.Queue are resp not implemented or not in release versions yet.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort But not in this respect. The `TThread` implementation captures exceptions into the `FFatalException` field, just as does Delphi.

Comment: Adding an exception handling block like this allows you to debug the exception without having to add the RTL/VCL/... debug DCUs to your project. Sometimes that eases the debugging process a lot.